# How to add Function on Onclick of a button in an echo?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is My Function

```
    function addorder($name,$price){
        echo $name." Price: ".$price;
        echo "<br>";
        alert("function worked");
    }
```

And Here is my Echo

```
echo "<input type='button'value='add'class='btnadd'onclick=\'addorder("'.$row["name".'","'.$row["price"].'");\'>";
```

I have tried many solution in stackoverflow, but the function won't work when i click the add button

Comment: You can't call a server function directly from client. Your best way is to use `ajax` to send request with some params that will lead to desired function call. Another way is by using forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I will clarify the things that you one must know when they are newbie to php and javascript.

So when you hit a php, it generates some output(for now consider it to be text). Once the php execution completes, the output text is sent to browser. It is only at browser that text is interpreted as HTML, Javascript, and CSS.
So the functioning that you are trying to achieve that is calling some function on click of a button, will invoke a function that is defined in javascript.

So from php you will be required to generate javascript as text which will include a function (javascript method addorder) .

The exmple code is below to make one understand how it works.

PHP code:

```
 ?>
<input type="button" value='add' onclick='addorder("<?php echo $name; ?>","<?php echo $price; ?>");' />
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function addorder(name, price){
             alert(name + ' : ' + price);
     }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML is a client side language. PHP is a server side language. HTML can not directly interact with PHP. You can only do this by using ajax calls at a specific url which in turn call that particular function with required data or by using RESTful or SOAP Apis.

Answer (score 0):

use function parameters to pass server side values to front end. modify your js function to see how it works.

```
function addOrder(name, price){
 alert(name ＋ " 's price is " + price);

 // do stuffs with server side values

}
```

Comment: This is almost a good answer. You're absolutely right, but I think the meaning is still a little bit unclear because your answer is so short.